# GPS stopping, onPause()

Tags: android, gps, location, onpause

In my app when I start using GPS I can’t stop it, it doesn’t matter if I push the back or home button the Toast appears (I put 0, 0 at the requestLocationUpdate call to see if it does that)

It apears that the onPause method (in which when I push the back/home button enters) the removeUpdates call doesn’t do enything. Or something else is the problem? please help me cause for the last 3 days I’m stuck with this problem. The logic of the app: I have a button which I push then it checks which provider is active whatIsEnabled() method

My code is:

```
public class Map extends MapActivity {
private MapView mapView;
private MapController mc;
private GeoPoint p;
private Context context;
private Drawable drawable;
private Bundle instanceState;
private EditText et;
private ImageButton connect, layers, location;
private int i = 1;
//private Settings settings;
private LocationManager locationManager;
private LocationListener locationListener;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    instanceState = savedInstanceState;
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    context = getApplicationContext();

    //settings = new Settings();

    //to zoom
    mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapView);
    mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);

    et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.address);

    connect = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.connect_icon);
    connect.setOnClickListener(connect_button);


    layers = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.layers);  
    layers.setOnClickListener(layer_button);

    //locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    //locationListener = new Coordonates(drawable, mapView, Map.this);
    location = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.location_icon);
    location.setOnClickListener(location_button);



    //markers
    drawable = this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.blue_pin);

}

private OnClickListener connect_button = new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(Map.this, Connection.class);
        Map.this.startActivity(myIntent);
    }
};

private OnClickListener layer_button = new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        if(i%2 != 0) {
            mapView.setStreetView(true);
            mapView.setSatellite(false);
        }
        else {
            mapView.setSatellite(true);
            mapView.setStreetView(false);
        }
        i++;
    }
};

private OnClickListener location_button = new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        //registerLocListener();

        locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        locationListener = new Coordonates(drawable, mapView, Map.this);

        switch(Settings.whatIsEnabled()) {
        case 1: {
            Toast.makeText(context, "Location services disabled",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            break;
        }
        case 2: {
            Toast.makeText(context, "Location obtained via GPS satellites",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Toast.makeText(context, "Waiting for location",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            System.out.println("1");
            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0,locationListener);//50
            if(Coordonates.getLatitude() == 0)  
                Toast.makeText(context, "No GPS signal",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            System.out.println("2");
            break;
        }
        case 3: {
            Toast.makeText(context, "Location obtained via Wi-Fi/mobile network",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListener);//1000
            if(Coordonates.getLatitude() == 0)  
                Toast.makeText(context, "No Wi-Fi/mobile network signal",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            break;
        }/*
        case 4: {
            Toast.makeText(context, "Location obtained via the best provider available",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            locationManager.
            break;
        }*/
        }
    }
};
/*
protected void onResume() {

    super.onResume();
}*/

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    System.out.println("a intrat in onPause()");
    if(locationManager != null) {
        locationManager.removeUpdates(locationListener);
    }
    locationListener = null;
    locationManager = null;
    super.onPause();
}
```

Comment: Do you get the output "a intrat in onPause()" in the console? Check the console and reply back

Answer (score 0):

I developed a similar application but I put the

`locationManager.removeUpdates(locationListener);`

in the onCreate() method after I get location rather in the onPause(). The problem with putting it in onPause() is that it will be called when you leave (pause) the activity. Since I am not tracking the user's movement, I stop the listener once I get their location.

This might not be useful you are developing the application for a different functionality than I did.

Good Luck!